# Java JList formatting vs. functionality of JTable

Tags: java, jtable, jlist, defaulttablemodel, defaultlistmodel

I’m trying to display a listing of patient data in such a way that names are on the left side of my JList and identification numbers are all aligned neatly over to the right. 
I have looked at and even implemented the use of a JTable for this task as it does provide the neat column structure I’m hoping to achieve in this project but there is some functionality I’m either not aware of how to implement or I feel is lacking in a JTable.

1. The inability to transition my list based on alphanumeric keys. This is a primary way an end user to quickly search through the list as when populated it can be well over 800 rows in length. (example: typing a 's' to transition to the portion of the list starting with 's's)
2. Visually I’m not a fan of row selection with JTables; with a two column structure it is apparent that there is a break between the two columns, unlike with the JList a nice smooth seamless highlighted selection. All grid lines have been turned off as well as the use of cell editing as an FYI.

I’ve included what I feel is the relevant code. I’m hoping for some direction on if what I’m asking can be accomplished with a JList or is there a way to better manipulate a JTable? I did not find anything within either the JTable [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) nor the JList [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) I felt answered my question on this.

```
  package mosaiqToCTWorklist;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PatientSelectionWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnActivePatients;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnInactivePatients;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnAllPatients;
    private JButton btnSendSelection;
    private JList<String> patients;
    private JScrollPane scrollBar;
    private ButtonGroup btngroup;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    private List<PatientData> ptList;
    //  private HashMap<String,PatientData> ptRecords;
    private Label lblPatientTotal;
    private Label lblDOB;
    private Label lblAge;
    private Label lblGender;
    private Label label_4;


    public PatientSelectionWindow(List<PatientData> ptList) {
        this.ptList = ptList;
        activePatients();
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Mosaiq to CT Worklist");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 534, 378);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        patients = new JList<String>(model);
        scrollBar = new JScrollPane(patients);
        scrollBar.setBounds(10, 11, 376, 328);
        scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        contentPane.add(scrollBar);

        rdbtnActivePatients = new JRadioButton("Active Patients");
        rdbtnActivePatients.addActionListener(this);
        rdbtnActivePatients.setSelected(true);
        rdbtnActivePatients.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        rdbtnActivePatients.setBounds(392, 35, 130, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnActivePatients);

        rdbtnInactivePatients = new JRadioButton("Inactive Patients");
        rdbtnInactivePatients.addActionListener(this);
        rdbtnInactivePatients.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        rdbtnInactivePatients.setBounds(392, 61, 130, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnInactivePatients);

        rdbtnAllPatients = new JRadioButton("All Patients");
        rdbtnAllPatients.addActionListener(this);
        rdbtnAllPatients.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        rdbtnAllPatients.setBounds(392, 86, 130, 23);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnAllPatients);

        btngroup = new ButtonGroup();
        btngroup.add(rdbtnActivePatients);
        btngroup.add(rdbtnInactivePatients);
        btngroup.add(rdbtnAllPatients);

        btnSendSelection = new JButton("Send Selected");
        btnSendSelection.addActionListener(new DicomTransfer());
        btnSendSelection.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnSendSelection.setBounds(396, 154, 126, 38);
        contentPane.add(btnSendSelection);

        Label label = new Label("Show");
        label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 11));
        label.setBounds(392, 10, 62, 22);
        contentPane.add(label);

        lblPatientTotal = new Label("");
        setPatientCount();
        lblPatientTotal.setBounds(392, 115, 130, 29);
        contentPane.add(lblPatientTotal);

        Label label_1 = new Label("D.O.B:");
        label_1.setBounds(396, 252, 38, 22);
        contentPane.add(label_1);

        Label label_2 = new Label("Age:");
        label_2.setBounds(396, 226, 30, 22);
        contentPane.add(label_2);

        Label label_3 = new Label("Gender:");
        label_3.setBounds(396, 280, 46, 22);
        contentPane.add(label_3);

        lblDOB = new Label("1984-10-10");
        lblDOB.setBounds(434, 252, 88, 22);
        contentPane.add(lblDOB);

        lblAge = new Label("64");
        lblAge.setBounds(426, 226, 38, 22);
        contentPane.add(lblAge);

        lblGender = new Label("male");
        lblGender.setBounds(444, 280, 62, 22);
        contentPane.add(lblGender);

        label_4 = new Label("Currently Selected Pt.");
        label_4.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 11));
        label_4.setBounds(392, 198, 130, 22);
        contentPane.add(label_4);
    }

    private void setPatientCount() {
        Integer patientTotal = model.size();
        lblPatientTotal.setText("Total Patients: " + patientTotal.toString());
    }

    private void activePatients() {
        model.clear();
        for(PatientData pt : ptList){
            if (pt.getActiveStatus() == 1) {
                model.addElement(pt.getLastName() + ", " + pt.getFirstName() + " "
                        + pt.getMiddleName() + " " + pt.getMHN() );
            }
        }
    }

    private void inActivePatients() {
        model.clear();
        for(PatientData pt : ptList){
            if (pt.getActiveStatus() == 0) {
                model.addElement(pt.getLastName() + ", " + pt.getFirstName() + " "
                        + pt.getMiddleName() + " " + pt.getMHN() );
            }
        }
    }

    public void allPatients() {
        model.clear();
        for(PatientData pt : ptList){
            model.addElement(pt.getLastName() + ", " + pt.getFirstName() + " "
                    + pt.getMiddleName() + " " + pt.getMHN() );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == rdbtnActivePatients) {
            activePatients();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == rdbtnAllPatients) {
            allPatients();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == rdbtnInactivePatients) {
            inActivePatients();
        }

        patients.setModel(model);
        setPatientCount();
    }
    }
```

(yes I’m aware I’m using fruit……I’m hungry) Examples of what I get vs what more along the lines of what I was hoping for. It just makes it easier for the end user to read I feel.

[image][image]

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: One of the features that `JTable` will provide is the ability to filter the table results.  This means you can provide in built searching or filtering of data without the need to have to reload the data set from the database if you don't want to

Comment: Valid, sort of excited this is one of my first intros into the Swing API. Based on your comment I might trying playing with the [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html). I believe this is the direction you are indicating?

Comment: At present my result set is capture is the list that is passed into this class which then my model is built upon, no need to re-query the db, concern about new data being entered isn't a factor either. Is filtering a table preferred to rebuilding the model? I guess I'm not sure what are the advantages/disadvantages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with the difference between models and views and their responsibilities.

It's the responsibility of a model to "model" the data in some way.  This typically means providing information about the size of the model (the number of items contained within) and access to the data in some way (getters).

It's the responsibility of the view to decide how best to show this data.

What does all this have to do you with your question?  Actually, every thing.  The model shouldn't try and pre-format the data, but instead, should contain the raw data.  It's the view's responsibility to decide how to show that data.

For example, you might have one `JList` which shows the patient data in the form of `{mhn} {first name} {last name}`, but another `JList` that wants `{lastname}, {first name} {givenname}`...

You don't want to be creating new models each time, instead, you want a simple model that contains just the raw data, which could be passed to either of these views and allow them to decide how to display this information.  Before you tell me that "this won't happen"...just know, it will, because that's how users are...

So, instead of...

```
private DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
private List<String> ptList;
```

You want to use something more like...

```
private DefaultListModel<PatientData> model = new DefaultListModel<PatientData>();
private List<PatientData> ptList;
```

Now, this will raise the next question of "how do you format the raw data?".  Swing provides a concept of renderers (and in some case editors) which provide an extendable and pluggable API which provides you the means by which you can provide a "formatter" to classes like `JList`, `JTable` and `JTree`.  This is an important concept to understand as it is widely used within Swing.

Start by having a look at [How to use Lists, Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)

Now, because we're dealing with structured data, things become a little more difficult, as `JList` isn't designed to deal with structured data of this nature.  Remember, each cell/row is rendered individually, without context to any other cell or row, this makes laying out complex structures very difficult with a `JList`, for example...

One approach would be to create our own `ListCellRenderer` from sratch.  This is problematic, as much of the formatting of a cell comes from the `DefaultListCellRenderer`, so we need to provide all of the formatting ourselves, and because we're using multiple components, that compounds the issue.

The following renderer will produce the following output...

[image: Render by panel]

```
public class NameFirstWithMNHListCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<PatientData> {

    private static final Border SAFE_NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
private static final Border DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
protected static Border noFocusBorder = DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER;

    private JLabel name;
    private JLabel mhn;

    public NameFirstWithMNHListCellRenderer() {
        name = new JLabel();
        mhn = new JLabel();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(name, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(mhn, gbc);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends PatientData> list, PatientData value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        name.setText(value.getFirstName() + " " + value.getLastName());
        mhn.setText(value.getMHN());
        formatBackground(name, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        formatBackground(mhn, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        formatBackground(this, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        formatForeground(name, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        formatForeground(mhn, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        formatForeground(this, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        formatBorder(this, list, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        return this;
    }

    private Border getNoFocusBorder() {
    Border border = UIManager.getBorder("List.cellNoFocusBorder");
    if (System.getSecurityManager() != null) {
        if (border != null) return border;
        return SAFE_NO_FOCUS_BORDER;
    } else {
        if (border != null &&
                (noFocusBorder == null ||
                noFocusBorder == DEFAULT_NO_FOCUS_BORDER)) {
            return border;
        }
        return noFocusBorder;
    }
}

    protected void formatBorder(JComponent comp, JList<? extends PatientData> list, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Border border = null;
        if (cellHasFocus) {
            if (isSelected) {
                border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusSelectedCellHighlightBorder");
            }
            if (border == null) {
                border = UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder");
            }
        } else {
            border = getNoFocusBorder();
        }
        comp.setBorder(border);
    }

    protected void formatBackground(JComponent comp, JList<? extends PatientData> list, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Color bg = null;

        JList.DropLocation dropLocation = list.getDropLocation();
        if (dropLocation != null
                && !dropLocation.isInsert()
                && dropLocation.getIndex() == index) {

            bg = UIManager.getColor("List.dropCellBackground");

            isSelected = true;
        }

        if (isSelected) {
            comp.setBackground(bg == null ? list.getSelectionBackground() : bg);
        } else {
            comp.setBackground(list.getBackground());
        }

        comp.setOpaque(isSelected);

        setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
    }

    protected void formatForeground(Component comp, JList<? extends PatientData> list, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Color fg = null;

        JList.DropLocation dropLocation = list.getDropLocation();
        if (dropLocation != null
                && !dropLocation.isInsert()
                && dropLocation.getIndex() == index) {

            fg = UIManager.getColor("List.dropCellForeground");

            isSelected = true;
        }

        if (isSelected) {
            comp.setForeground(fg == null ? list.getSelectionForeground() : fg);
        } else {
            comp.setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }

        comp.setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        comp.setFont(list.getFont());

    }
}
```

Now, before you go running from the room screaming, this is just a demonstration of a single possible solution.  There are some other ways to achieve the same result, which are a little less complicated, but which introduce their own problems...

The long and short of it all is, `JList` simply isn't designed to support structured data in this way, this is why we have `JTable`...

A `JTable` on the other hand, is perfect for displaying structured data, and with some simple tweaks, can be made to "appear" seamless...

Lets start with `TableModel`...

```
public static class PatientTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        "First name",
        "Last name",
        "MHN"
    };

    private List<PatientData> rowData;

    public PatientTableModel() {
        rowData = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void add(PatientData... pd) {
        add(Arrays.asList(pd));
    }

    public void add(List<PatientData> pd) {
        rowData.addAll(pd);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    public PatientData getPatientDataAt(int row) {
        return rowData.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        PatientData pd = getPatientDataAt(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = pd.getFirstName();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = pd.getLastName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = pd.getMHN();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

This is responsible for defining the row and column structure, here I've broken the first name, last name and MHN over separate columns, this is a personal choice, you could combine the name columns if you wish...

Next, we need to prepare the `JTable`...

```
patients = new JTable(model);
patients.setShowGrid(false);
patients.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
patients.setShowVerticalLines(false);
patients.setRowMargin(0);
patients.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));
patients.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
TableRowSorter<PatientTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
patients.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

This sets the table up so that it won't display the horizontal or vertical grid lines and will reduce the padding between the cells to `0` making it appear as a seamless line of data...

Next, we need to prepare the model...

```
public PatientSelectionWindow(List<PatientData> ptList) {
    this.ptList = ptList;
    model.add(ptList);
    createWindow();
    activePatients();
}
```

You'll see in a minute, you no longer need the `ptList`...

Next, we need to alter the filtering...

```
private void activePatients() {
    RowFilter<PatientTableModel, Integer> rf = new RowFilter<PatientTableModel, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends PatientTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
            int row = entry.getIdentifier();
            PatientData pd = entry.getModel().getPatientDataAt(row);
            return pd.getActiveStatus() == 1;
        }

    };
    ((TableRowSorter) patients.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(rf);
    setPatientCount();
}

private void inActivePatients() {
    RowFilter<PatientTableModel, Integer> rf = new RowFilter<PatientTableModel, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends PatientTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
            int row = entry.getIdentifier();
            PatientData pd = entry.getModel().getPatientDataAt(row);
            return pd.getActiveStatus() != 1;
        }

    };
    ((TableRowSorter) patients.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(rf);
    setPatientCount();
}

public void allPatients() {
    ((TableRowSorter) patients.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(null);
    setPatientCount();
}
```

The three methods basically take advantage of the `RowFilter` support available within the `JTable` API, this means you don't need to physically touch the model or change it or manage the data separately, it is all taken care of for you...

And then we end up with the following result...

[image]

Take a look at:

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)
- [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

for more details

Comment: Wow, really do appreciate the well thought out response. Just wanted to personally thank you. I'm taking some time to work through what you've provided. Will defiantly try and provide an update for discussion. Thank you

Comment: I hope it highlights some of the differences between `JList` and `JTable`...you should always be looking towards making it easier for the user to read information and looking to use the right tools for the job ;)